# Save predicate orderBy on page refresh

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to save the orderBy so that if a user sorts the data then refreshes the page, the last sort (column and ascending/descending) is still apparent?

Here is my view.

```
<table>
<tr class="sortheaders">
    <th class="small"> </th>
    <th class="medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="order('name');" title="Sort by Name">Name</a></th>
    <th class="medium"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="order('age');" title="Sort By Age">Age</a></th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="result in results | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{ result.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ result.age }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll need some sort of browser level storage or to store the sorting on a server somewhere since a page refresh makes a new JavaScript instance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to save data over a refresh would be by saving cookies in the user's browser. You can inject an `ngCookies` module. Read more about cookies and how to use the module [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies).

Comment: This would mean initially the view would render in the order it is retrieved from backend, and then the cookie read/update code would kick in, I presume